# Enforcing Column Level Constraints on Iceberg Table

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-athena, data-lake, apache-iceberg

I am creating an iceberg table using Athena. I want to specify some constraints (NOT NULL, value greater than a specific value) on the columns. How can I do that? I tried specifying the column as NOT NULL but it doesn't allow me.

Answer (score 0):

NOT NULL will define field required:  true in meta….json file

Spark per default checks the nullification
Spark option check-nullability

In your case AWS Glue might not support this yet
https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/7771